# Debian Jessie updates

Tags: debian, upgrade

I've installed Jessie about 2 months ago (from a fresh download from Testing), and I never see package updates notifications. And I am never asked to download anything.

Is there something I have to activate before I see this?

Comment: You give very little information about what you have installed, e.g. what desktop etc.  If you're installing a not-yet-released version it's expected you know what you're doing... With `apt update; apt full-upgrade` you can manually upgrade to the latest state.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the package list and print the available updates by executing

```
apt-get update
apt-get --just-print upgrade
```

You can update your system by executing the same command without `--just-print`:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

You'll need to be root or have sudo privileges to execute the above commands.

As for getting notifications, take a look at [`update-notifier`](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-packagekit/stable/). It's a GTK interface which supplies you with a  notification icon for updates. ([link to website](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-packagekit/stable/))

Comment: You first need to do `apt-get update` to fetch the latest package lists.

Comment: You are right, I've included it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want an automatic update notifier (not just `apt-get`). Try with the `update-notifier` package.

Comment: holy duckballs! I got interested in the `update-notifier` and wanted to install it. It would take 212MB of additional disk space on my `Jessie` with `i3`. Is there something similar - but a little less dependent on such a load of packages?

Comment: I think the notifier is a package that some DE have developed for their users. update-notifier is the one for gnome, I've seen update-notifier-kde so I guess the notifier is DE dependant, but having your question here awoke my curiosity, and making a google search I found http://www.pontikis.net/blog/simple-steps-to-update-a-debian-server, there you can find `apticron` which is a simple script that will send an email when new updates are available.